# Are the notes on the ledger lines above the bass clef played by the left hand or sometimes by the right hand?

Tags: piano

I am trying to play a piece by Bach on the piano which is written as 4-part harmony (so 2 notes in the treble clef and two in the bass clef) and I was wondering if the left hand should always play the bottom two notes or is it ok if the left hand only fingers one note sometimes while the right hand fingers the tenor part as well as the alto and soprano?

Comment: Could you maybe add a photo of the measures in question?

Comment: The question I've proposed as a duplicate is just one of many questions here in which the answer is to have the left or right hand play notes that would typically be assigned to the other. Search for [fingering].

Comment: When you're playing Bach, you play the internal lines however you can.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 is correct.  I was playing through some of the French Suites earlier today, and it's clear that Bach was not particularly strict about keeping each hand on one staff.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:** you can play notes with whatever hands/fingers you choose! This can be based on your personal preference, skill level, or the size of your hands.

For 4-part piano pieces, it is typical to play two voices per hand, as it balances out each hand and prevents over-stretching. In the unique case that the tenor note is easier to hit with the right hand, even while playing the alto and soprano notes at the same time, I wouldn't hesitate to advise using the right hand.

Fingerings are one of the only classical notations that you can modify without worrying about disrupting the intention of the piece. If it's more **comfortable** for you to play with a certain finger position, and it doesn't negatively affect the speed and dynamics of your playing, go for it. Everyone has different hands and preferences.

That being said, if you provide sheet music and the specific bar(s) that you are questioning, folks here (including myself) would be happy to give advice for the average player and hand position.

Hope that helps!

Comment: The only exception I'd say to this is where crossing a hand over is part of the showmanship of a piece.  A fair number of pieces have arpeggios and so on that a good performer could play with one hand easily enough, but which somehow look cooler when you use them both. :D

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the writing of the piece concerned: in 4-part writing, generally speaking, the soprano and alto parts are written in the treble clef, and the tenor and bass written in the bass clef. S tails up, A tails down, T tails up, B tails down. They rarely cross each other - each keeps to their own 'territory'.

That said, there may well be times when notes are close enough to be played with the 'wrong' hand. Provided those can be played sounding as if they were played with the 'right' (correct) hand, it matters not. Audiences are there to *listen* to the performance, not to dissect whether the notes are played by the 'correct' hand - or fingers for that matter..!

Answer (score 1):

By all means.  Never be a slave to notation if it causes stretches, strains, twists or awkward positions.  Many editors will engrave the music to look good rather than clutter it with ledger lines and collisions. As a result they will put notes in the treble clef that the LH should and could easily play and teachers don't catch it. The student then plays it with their RH which may result in one or two lines being sloppy, uneven or broken and will definitely  create strain which over the years can turn into a "repetitive strain" injury because of dual muscular pulls or vector forces. There is no such thing as repetitive strain, only improper movement.  I am an organist and often while playing a simple four part hymn, I will play only the soprano line in my RH and the alto (in the treble line) and tenor (in the bass line) in my LH and of course, the bass voice in my feet. This is how hymns should be written out but it is expected the student or teacher will know this but, they often don't and play it as written.  The music of Bach is obviously much more complicated. Think of his music as being played by four individual instruments.

Photocopy your music and just for fun, take two or four different colored highlighters and highlight the lines and you will often see the two internal voices intersecting or invading another clef.  Think of the pieces as being played by four instruments and they each have their own line.  Play the lines individually. Then take a pencil and scrawl a half circle up or down to indicate which hand can easily assist in maintaining a smooth line. Stretching the hand to play what is on one staff will compromise the fluidity and phrasing of the individual line.   Not to mention, extend an invitation to the dreaded cArPaL tUnNeL sYnDrOmE or, Median Nerve Entrapment.

Go to YouTube and search for your piece with "fingering" or "colorized."  Chances are someone has already done the work for you.  By sharing voices between two hands you can help avoid abducting which is strain. Many students do it because nobody tells us not to.

One of my teachers could barely reach an octave and for years she stretched and strained to reach the notes as written and permanently injured her thumb. If it doesn't feel good, either you are doing something wrong or the composer/editor was unrealistic.